# NGINX FastCGI configuration for multiple servers behind ELB on AWS

Tags: nginx, caching, fastcgi

We are using NGINX FastCGI Cache for our WordPress application. To support higher concurrency, we are running 2 WordPress instances on separate EC2 instances behind AWS ELB, with shared filesystem on EFS and the MySQL database. When we run 1 server with 3000 concurrent users, it all works fine. But when we add the second server it chokes the database even for 3000 concurrent user test which in fact, only 1 server was supporting. Our theory is that it could have something to do with FastCGI cache, but we are not able to nail it. We have the following cache path:

`fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache`

We are thinking of moving this to EFS but we that could add latency. But we are wondering if there is a way to Shard the cache or any other way to handle this.

If someone has done this, can you please share the NGINX or FastCGI configuration?